# XLOOKUP Array of items, items are delimited in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell with multiple IP addresses. Here is an example (with fake IP addresses)

```
   A
1  11.111.11.111, 22.222.22.222, 33.333.33.333, 44.444.44.444
```

I'm trying to lookup a value in another sheet that corresponds to one of these IP addresses. I only need to return one value even if the others also have values.

```
   A              B
1  IP             TimeStamp
2  22.222.22.222  06/13/2023
3  44.444.44.444  06/14/2023
```

The end result should be:
`06/13/2023`

Comment: Try: `=@XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,", "),$E$2:$E$3,$F$2:$F$3,,1)` or this `=@FILTER(F2:F3,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(E2:E3,TEXTSPLIT(A1,,", "))))`

Comment: Try either of the one: `=@TOCOL(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A1,,", "),E2:E3,F2:F3),3)`

Comment: I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong. The first one gives me a name error. The second gives me a calc error and the last one gives me a name error.

Comment: `#NAME?` error means one of the functions used in the formulas don't support your version of `Excel` so it seems like for `TEXTSPLIT()` and `#CALC!` error occurs when one of the scenarios has not met. May I know what is your Excel Version?

Comment: Looks like `TEXTSPLIT()` is not supported. My version is 16.74 Excel for Mac.

Comment: try this : `=@FILTER(F2:F3,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(E2:E3,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ",REPT(" ",100)),ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,4))*100-99,100)))))` let me know i shall post it as an answer

Comment: Almost there. This works if the IP address is listed on the other tab. If not it gives back a `#CALC!` error. So I need it to bring back empty if not found. Is there a better way than just wrapping it in an `IFERROR` function?

Comment: Ok. Just one thing I'd like in your answer if possible. Can you Change the E column to A and the F Column to B to match what I have. I understood and corrected it but others may be confused. Also, what is the "@" in the beginning of the function?

Comment: All updated in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above either of the one should work for you:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F1` --> This will work for your version of `Excel for MAC`

```
=@FILTER(B2:B3,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A3,
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(E1,", ",REPT(" ",100)),ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,4))*100-99,100)))),"")
```

---

Other alternatives:

```
=@FILTER(B2:B3,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A3,TEXTSPLIT(E1,,", "))))
```

---

```
=@TOCOL(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(E1,,", "),A2:A3,B2:B3),3)
```

---

use the last param of the <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> as `""` which is <kbd>[if_empty]</kbd> therefore <kbd>IFERROR()</kbd> is not required. The use of **implicit intersection** `@` in the formula is because it reduces the multiple returns to a single value and retains the top left value which is required **[MS_Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34)**

---

Comment: Will this work if there are more than 4 IP addresses in cell E1? I have one cell that has 6 ip addresses and the 5th one is the only one that has a value to bring back.

Comment: @DanCue change the number from `4` to any like `26`/`27`/`100` etc. since you had posted one example so assumed you will be having 4 IP addresses.  `=@FILTER(B2:B3,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A3,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(E1,", ",REPT(" ",100)),ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,100))*100-99,100)))),"")`

Comment: Perfect. I had just realized that right before you posted this. All working now.

Comment: Sounds Good. Glad it worked on your end =)

Comment: @DanCue one more thing if you want to make that number `4` to be dynamic you can add few more functions but i was trying to avoid it, only an option though using this `LEN(E1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E1,",",""))+1` so the formula will be `=@FILTER(B2:B3,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A3,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(E1,", ",REPT(" ",100)),ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(E1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E1,",",""))+1))*100-99,100)))),"")`

Comment: Interesting. That would make it more efficient. I think I will do that.

Comment: Sure thing go ahead.