# Comma-separated indices to lookup in a reference array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a column with a bunch of comma-separated numbers, like A1 has 43,91,21 B2 has 12,84 etc...

And then there is in another sheet of the workbook, a reference array with the above-mentioned indices in one column, and the color/material/usage each index corresponds to.

So, I'd like to calculate A2 to the values that correspond to each of the indices, like red,green,blue

I've searched online and all I can find is the [exact opposite](https://exceltutorialworld.com/vlookup-each-comma-separated-value-in-one-cell-in-excel/) of what I need.

Is what I need easily achievable? From a programmer's perspective, I'd need to explode each index, look it up in the reference array, then concatenate the corresponding values.

In Excel is there any formula that does that for me?

Take for example these two arrays:

| COLORS |
| --- |
| 44,26 |
|  |
| 95 |
| 35,45,21 |
| 23 |

| Index | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 26 | yellow |
| 35 | silver |
| 44 | blue |
| 45 | orange |
| 57 | purple |
| 95 | magenta |

TIA!

Comment: Does your version of Excel support `TEXTSPLIT` and `TEXTJOIN` and `XLOOKUP`?

Comment: It's Excel 2021. TEXTJOIN, I've used it before. XLOOKUP, I've checked, and it's supported. TEXTSPLIT is not there...

Comment: Use `FILTERXML()` or a combination of `TRIM`, `MID()` , `SUBSTITUTE()` and `REPT()`

Comment: But why doesn't my Excel support `TEXTSPLIT()`? It's 
Microsoft Office LTSC Professional Plus 2021 Version 2307 (Version 2307 Build 16.0.16626.20170) 64-bit

Comment: `LTSC 2021` is an `enterprise` version as far I know which is not `MS365` **enterprise** version. There is a difference between both the versions. More details **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/ltsc2021/overview)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya could you help me with combining the three functions you mentioned above?

Comment: If you will not use the Excel web then use the `FILTERXML()` there are some examples here. `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",100)), COLUMN(A1:ZZ1)*100-99,100))`

Comment: Look at this example: **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76566296/8162520)** same question

Comment: Use this one: `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",100)),ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",))+1))*100-99,100))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255007/discussion-between-faye-d-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formulas:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=IF(A2="","",TEXTJOIN(", ",1,XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A2,",")+0,E:E,F:F,"")))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=IF(A2="","",TEXTJOIN(", ",1,XLOOKUP(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",100)),ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",))+1))*100-99,100))/1,E:E,F:F,"")))
```

---